# Cordova: (ion-google-place) google map api callback not working on Android Phone

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, visual-studio-cordova

i am using ion-google-place directive in my ionic project and when i run it in the ripple I can see that this directive works as expected, however when i deploy it on my Android phone the search bar comes up but when i type no drop down is shown.

I tried to debug the code and can see the issue to be around the following code:

`var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

```
geocoder.geocode(req, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        scope.$apply(function () {
            scope.locations = results;
        });
    } else {
        // @TODO: Figure out what to do when the geocoding fails
        console.log("error getting google place...");
    }
});
```

the callback function is never called when running within the android phone, however from ripple its working.

Any ideas as to what I may be missing ?

**EDIT 1:**
I created a Blank Cordova project and added the refrences to angular and google map. Then added a button and added a ng-onclick to that button as below

```
$scope.onButtonClick = function () {
        var api = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
        api.getPlacePredictions({ input: "Banga" }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                console.log("google place... success");

            } else {
                // @TODO: Figure out what to do when the geocoding fails
                console.log("error getting google place...");
            }
        });
```

Now I see that `google` is not defined when debugging the Android Phone, where as same when being debugged in ripple, it is working.

is there something on the phone that can prevent the maps from being available to the app?

Regards
Kiran

Comment: There is definitely something useful in the console - log, error or failed request.

Comment: @KateMihalikova Thanks! but where can I look for that? in the VS.Net output there is so much of logging happening, I don't see anything useful in there.

Comment: You can debug application through remote debug. Here is more information http://matthewgladney.com/blog/angular/how-to-debug-ionic-android-applications/

Comment: @ArtBase: Yes, thats the way I am working on the application, unfortunately in this case I see no exception nor does it reach the `if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)` part of the code. I believe that only option to get an actual error from the google map api is to atleast get a call back. I have also verified multiple times that the `geocoder` is proper google object. I tried to put a packet watcher on  the phone, but even there I see nothing captured to  go to google. Anything else I can try? did I miss a plugin bu any chance.

Comment: When using remote debugging, you have all Chrome developer tools available. You can look into the Network tab to see if the request is even fired.